# Should I use UI framework with three.js or vanilla-js to create an dynamic UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, three.js

I am trying to develop a 3d-editor with three.js. I know javascript and three.js but I am not familiar with web-dev in depth and never tried UI frameworks. While mrdoob's editor uses plain javascript for UI elements, I am not sure which method will be more beneficial for me? To use a framework like react.js or vue.js; or go with plain javascript for UI elements.

Project owner planning to have dynamic and complex UI elements like a tutorial wizard, a console or fields that will be dynamically change with data coming from server.

So what are the benefits and drawbacks of using pure js or frameworks, considering it will be a three.js project.

And should I use library's like react-three or vue-threejs, or start with integrating three.js scene to framework for the sake of stability?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand what is those framework trying to do for you

- React, Vue, Angular is abstracting DOM manipulation when state changes. And they are mature enough to adopt in production
- react-three, vue-threejs is abstracting Canvas/SVG/WebGL manipulation away when state changes.

In theory it is possible to build every product without any framework. But using them will save lots of time and give huge benifit for maintainability. But you need to put effort to learn it first.

So my answer is that for

**Small/POC project** - If you are not familiar with those frameworks, go ahead with plain javascript, jQuery to manipulate DOM and canvas directly. **But highly recommended to learn and use these frameworks in the future. It will increase your dev speed insanely**

**Large/Long-term project** - Do use React/Vue/Angular. Leverage your risk in adopting react-three/vue-threejs

Comment: `But because three.js is still not released in 1.0, you need to leverage the risk to adopt in production`

This is bad information. Three.js does not (and will not) follow traditional semver. There will not be a 1.0.0 release, just 0.X.0 releases. 
Discussion: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3102
Regarding 1.0.0 directly: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11396

Three.js is more than suitable for production usage, and is even currently receiving monthly releases.

Comment: @XanderLuciano Thanks for your comment. I changed my answer according to your suggestion. three.js's infinity versioning https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-version/ indeed confused me at that time. And I am using it in our production systems

Answer (score 1):

UI frameworks are great, they have done a lot of the hard work for you. Personally I really like VueJS, it's very lightweight but extremely powerful when it comes to creating SPAs. And from what you have said someone has already created a vue-three plugin